# Arcwise connected vs. path connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been reading [An Introduction to Algebraic Topology](https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-algebraic-topology/oclc/258460113&referer=brief_results) by Andrew Wallace.

His definition of an arcwise connected space is: a space in which there is a path between every two points.

In the [Wikipedia page for connected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), however, this is taken as the definition of a *path-connected space* not an arcwise connected space.

I am confused by this mix-up. Which one is more standard?

---

### Update

I'm quoting Wallace's definition of path and arcwise connectedness.

**Definition.** Let $E$ be a given topological space, and let $I$ denote the unit interval $0 \le t \le 1$, regarded as a subspace of the space of real numbers in the usual topology. Then a *path in $E$ joining two points $p$ and $q$ of $E$ is* defined to be a continuous mapping $f$ of $I$ into $E$ such that $f(0) = p$ and $f(1) = q$. The path will be said to *lie in a subset $A$ of $E$ if $f(I) \subset A$*.

**Definition.** A topological space $E$ is said to be *arcwise connected* if, for every pair of points $p$ and $q$ of $E$ there is a path in $E$ joining $p$ and $q$. If $A$ is a set in a topological space $E$, then $A$ is *arcwise connected* if every pair of points of $A$ can be joined by a path in $A$.

It seems that the situation is as [Henno Brandsma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma) pointed out: since most spaces are Hausdorff, path-connectedness is identified with arcwise connectedness and thus entirely omitted from the book. However, this strikes me as odd as I am actually interested in non-Hausdorff spaces such as those arising from computer science.

Comment: Are you reading it in English?

Comment: It might also be useful to note that some authors use arcwise connected to mean something stronger - there is a path between every pair of points that is a homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ to its image.

Comment: > Are you reading it in English?
Yes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do a good reading of that Wikipedia page: *path-connected* (usually) means that for every $a\neq b \in X$ there is a path from $a$ to $b$ (a continuous function from $[0,1]$ into the space $X$ with $p(0)=a$ and $p(1)=b$ is called a path from $a$ to $b$), while for an *arcwise connected* space $X$ there is the stronger requirement that there is such a $p$ but that **also** is an embedding (so that $p:[0,1] \to p[[0,1]]$ is a homeomorphism). So an arcwise connected space is always path-connected but the reverse sometimes does not hold (there are finite counterexamples, e.g.; obviously an arcwise connected space must be uncountable, while a finite space can be path-connected: a continuous map is a lot weaker than an embedding)

A theorem (not trivial though, it depends on the study of Peano continua) proves that if $X$ is Hausdorff (as is very common, e.g. all metric spaces, ordered spaces, many topological vector spaces etc.) then $X$ being path-connected implies $X$ is arcwise connected too. This can be quite useful to know.

So in practice these notions coincide, but there are marginal examples where the notions differ.

Maybe for your first author *path* actually means a homeomorphic copy of $[0,1]$ and he really defines what most texts would call arcwise connectedness. Check his definition of path.

Comment: It is worth highlighting again that for Hausdorff spaces both concepts agree. Then, if one deals with manifolds or more generally with CW-complexes there is no difference at all.

Comment: @Dog_69 Correction: If one deals with manifolds endowed with their manifold topologies, there is no difference at all. There are instances where one may want to come topologies on a manifold, e.g., in Kobayashi hyperbolicity one studies how the manifold topology compares with the topology induced by the Kobayashi pseudo-distance.

Comment: @AmorFati Yes, that it was I meant. Thanks for the nuance